# String serialization in MySQL db or in Java program

Tags: java, mysql, string

I am going to be doing some heavy work saving with Object serialization into string and saving into a DB. Each object has arround 100 characters and all objects are saved in a single row field. The thing is sometimes I want to get substrings or split the data and get a piece at certain location or other `String` manipulations. Should this be done in `MySQL` or by the Java program?.

Also is there a way to functionally optimize my queries since the expected size of the fields are going to be about `VARCHAR 20k`.

Comment: If you wanted to use mySQL you could append something to the end of each element to act as a delimiter(I like to use" //") and then split the string into its parts within Java, storing the elements in an arraylist.

Comment: @Joris That's what I am doing. I am talking about for example, what would be faster if I have 100 elements with delimiter and I want to get from element 72 - 108 or insert string at element 48. Is this faster to get all the field from the DB and manipulate them in the program or use MySQL String manipuulation methods?

Comment: It would be faster to have each element stored in its own row with a unique key of an incremented int and just use the mySQL statement `select textValue from exampleTable where key > 71 && key < 109` I think you can use `&&`  but that's the general idea

Comment: @Joris How woud I go about if I have to delete a record to organize the unique key accordingly?

Comment: The thing is in some cases it's better to not delete but rather to flag as active/inactive.  At that point I would say construct your database so that it has three columns: key, textValue, active.  Your key obviously is the incremented value, your textValue is your string, and your active is either a 1 or a 0.  1 being active, 0 being inactive.  If you want to "delete" just set that textValue's active value to 0.  Your new mySQL statement would then be `select textValue from exampleTable where key > 71 && key < 109 and active = 1`

Comment: @Joris wouldn't that eventually mike my table huge and more resource consuming to go through?

Comment: You won't have to worry about that.  However, some companies do like Amazon or Facebook.  They use a noSQL database instead which is very interesting but I wouldn't recommend it to you because you're probably not processing data on that large of a scale.  You'll be fine, I doubt your db will ever get that big

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107249/discussion-between-martinstone-and-joris).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java serialization, the resulting output is *opaque*, that is, you cannot look inside the serialized data and extract bits and pieces without reloading it back into a Java JVM.

If you want to do anything in SQL with the data, then it has to be stored in the database in its primitive (i.e. unserialized) form.

Comment: I am not using Java serialization, I am using a String based serialization method I  implemented to save the objects separated by a delimited